# My app not showed in playstore compatibilty list

Tags: kotlin, android-tv, leanback

I've created app with android studio for android tv and it run on android studio virtual machine but after i've pubblished it on playstore it isn't compatible with android tv.

I've declared attributes in manifest but i've the same issues.
Anyone can help me.

Comment: Hy, did you follow [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start) ?

Comment: Yes i've follow it...if i use apk i've no problem to install the issue is if i try to install it via playstore

Comment: On the Goole Play Console, look in Release > Setup > Advanced Settings > Form factors (tab) - did you add or opt-in to "Android TV" ?